# How can I show some standard html code across any theme I install?

Tags: themes, custom-content

I have some custom code that sits inside `<head></head>`.  When I install a new WordPress theme I have to edit the `header.php` script each time.

Is there a way to always include my custom code inside the head tags even when installing a new WordPress theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a new plugin for this. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head

1. Create a new file in /wp-content/plugins/ called headerstuff.php (or whatever)
2. Drop the following code in it:

   > ```
   >  <?php
   >  function header_code() {
   >  $output .= ""; //code segment 
   >  echo $output;
   >  }
   >  add_action('wp_head', 'header_code');
   >  ?>
   > ```
3. Add your code between the quotation marks on the line starting with "$output".
4. Activate, done!

Comment: I am starting to really find my way around now, however I spent maybe 4 hours last night trying to work out the following:  

I want to now insert some html before any search results - someone does a search (may or may not get results) and I want above the results (be it posts or snippets) my chunk of code.

I actually got it working by using

`add_filter('the_content', 'myresults');`
`add_filter('the_posts', 'myposts');`

However didn't realise that some themes don't show a post - just a list of links to posts.

Any ideas?

My site is http://foundfor.me - this theme my technique works.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this presently -- see: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add_action-right-after-ltbodygt-tag. That forum post has two useful bits of code: a jQuery snippet to insert code just after <body>, and a link to a trac patch inserting a new action called body_open. That said, the latter requires a new line of code in every theme you use it in, so its utility is somewhat questionable.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - that have saved me many hours looking for something that doesn't exist!

Comment: No problem. It's really unfortunate that they didn't think to include such a hook, would probably be useful for AJAXy things. I get why it's not really that possible now, though; see the trac. Btw, if I've sufficiently answered your question, mind accepting my answer? Thanks!